# Animating a diagonal line from corner to corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a diagonal line across the page from one corner to another. The line should be diagonal no matter the format of the screen. I figured (or so I think) that I have to use `transform: rotate()` in CSS. Using jquery or Javascript, I tried returning and calculating the degree at which the line has to rotate for the given screen format. That argument should be passed to `rotate()`.

I've tried the following with jQuery and Javascript:

```
<script>

  $('#move').css('transform', 'rotate(-' + Math.atan2($(window).width(), $(window).height()) + 'rad)').show();

</script>
```

or

```
<script>

  document.querySelector('#move').style.transform = Math.atan2($(window).width(), $(window).height())+'rad';

</script>
```

And with CSS and HTML:

```
<style>
  #move {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: top left;


}

  @keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 0; transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {width:100%; background-color: blue;}
    }
</style>




<body>

<div id="move"></div>

</body>
```

The code draws a line across the screen, but it is not rotated. 
How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your `<script>` to the very bottom of `<body>`, so the code works after your DOM is loaded.

```js
const move = document.querySelector('#move')
const angle = Math.atan2(document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth);
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth / Math.cos(angle);

move.style.setProperty('--a', angle + 'rad');
move.style.setProperty('--w', width + 'px');
```

```css
html, body, #move {margin:0; padding:0}

#move {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: rotate(var(--a));
  transform-origin: top left;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  to {
    width: var(--w);
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="move"></div>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. The jQuery and JS examples were meant to show both my attempts, edited my question for clarification.